# Python csv without header

Tags: python, csv

With header information in csv file, city can be grabbed as:

```
city = row['city']
```

Now how to assume that csv file does not have headers, there is only 1 column, and column is city.

Comment: Have you read the csv documentation?  http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can still use your line, if you declare the headers yourself, since you know it:

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames=['city'])
    for row in cf:
        print row['city']
```

For more information check [`csv.DictReader`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv#csv.DictReader) info in the docs.

Another option is to just use positional indexing, since you know there's only one column:

```
with open('data.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.reader(f)
    for row in cf:
        print row[0]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [pandas.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function similarly to the way @nosklo describes, as follows:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("A2", header=None)
print df[0]
```

or

```
df = pandas.read_csv("A2", header=None, names=(['city']))
print df['city']
```

Answer (score 0):

For CSV file does not have headers, and there is more than 1 column, can add your other column names in order in the ***fieldnames=[]***

**Background:** I have a CSV of consisitng of hostname, followed by respective IP.

e.g.

```
PLNXXXXA, 10.10.10.1
PLNXXXXB, 10.10.10.2
```

I want to build my lookup that key is IP, and respective value is hostname to enrich my data. Below are the code:

```py
import csv
csv_file =r"4.1.6_lookup.csv"

# Initialize an empty lookup dictionary
lookup = {}

# Read from the CSV file and populate the lookup dictionary
with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=['hostname','IP'])
    for row in csv_reader:
        # Capitalize the hostname and remove any leading/trailing whitespaces
        hostname = row['hostname'].upper().strip()  
        lookup[row['IP']] = hostname
```

The output is going to be like:

```
{'10.10.10.1': 'PLNXXXXA', '10.10.10.2': 'PLNXXXXB'}
```

Hope this helps someone.
Thank you ;)

Answer (score -3):

I'm using a pandas dataframe object:

```
df=pd.read_sql(sql_query,data_connection)
df.to_csv(filename, header=False, index=False)
```

Don't know if that is the most Pythonic approach, but it gets the job done.

Comment: your code is reading sql though? And writing to csv? Did you read the question?