# How make a list with a csv file using flask?

Tags: python, csv, flask

I am doing a project with Flask, the point is:
In one route I generate a .csv file to download it with the information from MySQL like this
file.csv

```
1,17.0,46.0,2.80696,0.559892,0.534016,0.543017,24.25,22:30:00,2020-04-28
2,17.0,47.0,2.80884,0.559142,0.534016,0.537016,24.5,23:00:00,2020-04-28
3,16.0,53.0,2.80921,0.547517,0.534016,0.537016,24.5,23:30:00,2020-04-28
4,16.0,49.0,2.80959,0.548079,0.534016,0.537016,24.25,00:00:00,2020-04-29
```

For other hand, other route of my server has the option to upload the file but when upload the file i can see a plain text:
[This is the output when upload my file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z5QO.jpg)

The idea is to create a list from this plain text with the following structure:

```
dato[
   [1,17.0,46.0,2.80696,0.559892,0.534016,0.543017,24.25,22:30:00,2020-04-28],
   [2,17.0,47.0,2.80884,0.559142,0.534016,0.537016,24.5,23:00:00,2020-04-28],
   [3,16.0,53.0,2.80921,0.547517,0.534016,0.537016,24.5,23:30:00,2020-04-28],
   [4,16.0,49.0,2.80959,0.548079,0.534016,0.537016,24.25,00:00:00,2020-04-29]
]
```

I tried a lot of thing, but i cant make it.
Here is my app.py

```
@app.route('/upload',methods = ['POST'])
def upload_route_summary():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Create variable for uploaded file
        f = request.files['fileupload']  

        #store the file contents as a string
        fstring = f.read()
        
        #create list of dictionaries keyed by header row
        #csv_dicts = [{k: v for k, v in row.items()} for row in csv.DictReader(fstring.splitlines(), skipinitialspace=True)]

        #do something list of dictionaries
    return fstring
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you meant you want a list of lists, since your sample output looks like:

```
dato[
   [1,17.0,46.0,2.80696,0.559892,0.534016,0.543017,24.25,22:30:00,2020-04-28],
   [2,17.0,47.0,2.80884,0.559142,0.534016,0.537016,24.5,23:00:00,2020-04-28],
   [3,16.0,53.0,2.80921,0.547517,0.534016,0.537016,24.5,23:30:00,2020-04-28],
   [4,16.0,49.0,2.80959,0.548079,0.534016,0.537016,24.25,00:00:00,2020-04-29]
]
```

`csv.DictReader` requires a header line unless you provide `fieldnames` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)) ([another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3387191/python-csv-without-header)): `If fieldnames is omitted, the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldnames`

Providing field names, iterating through each row to access the tuples will get you your list of lists:

```
data = []
for row in csv.DictReader(fstring.splitlines(), fieldnames=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j']):
  data.append([item[1] for item in row.items()])
```

Alternatively, the `DictReader` document states: `If a row has more fields than fieldnames, the remaining data is put in a list and stored with the fieldname specified by restkey (which defaults to None)`

So you can pass in any empty list for `fieldnames` & access the whole list in `None`:

```
data = []
for row in csv.DictReader(fstring.splitlines(), fieldnames=[]):
    data.append(row[None])
```

Comment: Thanks, but when run your code i hace this problem
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: try decoding the fstring with `fstring = fstring.decode("utf-8")`