# How to get csv rows as array with Python csv?

Tags: python, csv

I have an csv file that looks like

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

and a code that looks like

```
import csv
def func():
    with open('zumatchende.csv', mode='r') as csv_datei:
        csv_datei=csv.DictReader(csv_datei, delimiter=";", dialect="excel")
        for row in csv_datei:
            print(row)



func()
```

i would have expected an output like

```
['a']
['b']
['c']
['d']
['e']
```

but i get

```
{'a':'b'}
{'a':'c'}
{'a':'d'}
{'a':'e'}
```

i used this often times before and i always got the row back as an array with each element of the row as one element of the array. I dont understand why this is now formated in another data type and even puts together 2 lines into one.
How can i fix this? Or what am I doing wrong?
The code that i used in other places which works fine looks the same, exept the file name.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387212/499721

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify `fieldnames` when you create the `DictReader`, it gets the field names from the first row.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to fetch the dictionary and printing the dictionary. Try to fetch the value instead of complete dictionary by using following code:
print(list(row['a'])

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:

```
with open('zumatchende.csv') as f:
    cf = csv.reader(f)
    row = [e[0] for e in cf]        
    
row

Out[14]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Long answer:

Per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), `DictReader` outputs a dictionary whose keys are given by the optional `fieldnames` parameter. If `fieldnames` is omitted, the values in the first row of file f will be used as the fieldnames.

See a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3387212/499721).

Comment: But i used this tool before and without mentioning the fieldnames. It always gave me just an array with the values from each row. Is it possible to get it like this again? since this list does not have any fieldnames